# What is the best way to show products based on two criterias (MySQL + Schema + maths)

Tags: php, mysql, schema, e-commerce, product

I am building a e-commerce website using MySQL. I am stuck with the following.

I have the

```
**products** table:  
    id  | sku 

**stocks** table:  
id  | product_id |quantity 

**orders** table:  
id  | status     | products
```

I want to know the best way to make SQL query that brings me the products that have 1 or more quantity. To get the quantity of a product: first you get the id from **products**, then you check the amount in **stocks** (a product_id can have more than 1 row, I want to add a new row everytime that our store recieve new stock) and subtract the total times that product_id appears on **orders** table and that row status is 3.

Or if you can suggest me a better way to do this, it would be awesome.

Really appreciate any help here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This joins products to stocks and gets a list of products where the value in quantity is more or equal one

Just realized you said product id can be stocks more than once therefore i suggest grouping by product id and summing the quantity

```
SELECT *, SUM(s.quantity) as 'products_total_quantity' FROM products p 
INNER JOIN stocks s on s.product_id = p.id 
GROUP BY p.id HAVING SUM(s.quantity) >=1
```

Comment: SUM() will automatically subtract negative entries so my answer should still work with your specs

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You are not substracting if you have a order with status 3 and if the JSON of the orders.products field contains the same product.id. How I can do that @jason-joslin?